# I want to apply css class as per below condition

Tags: php, css, loops

I want to apply css class as per below condition but after applying this code each content is repeated by 8 times and if i complete for loop before div then css classes are not getting applied.

```
    <?php $size=count($Spacategories);          
   for($i=0;$i<8;$i++){
    if($i==0 || $i==5){ ?>
    <li class="valign">
    <?php } elseif($i==1 || $i==7) { ?>
    <li class="lalign">
    <?php  } elseif($i==2 || $i==6) { ?>
    <li class="talign">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li class="ralign">
    <?php } ?>

        <div class="image">
            <img src="<?php echo $spacategory['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $spacategory['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $spacategory['name']; ?>" />

        </div>
       <div class="text">
            <h3><?php echo $spacategory['name']; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo substr($spacategory['description'],0,150); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo $spacategory['href']; ?>" class="learmmore"><?php echo $text_view_more; ?></a>
        </div>   
       </li>   
      <?php  } } ?>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code unsing this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

Change all instances of

```
$spacategory
```

to

```
$Spacategories[$i]
```

This will fix it.

Also, I don't see what's populating $text_view_more. You should probably change that to some data point from $Spacategories?

Finally, it seems you need to be looping based on the number of categories, so change

```
for($i=0;$i<8;$i++){
```

to

```
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `$spacategory` is not an item from `$spacategories` with the index `$i` in each iteration. You should have started the `for`:

```
$spacategory = $spacategories[$i];
```

or use a `foreach` instead:

```
<?php
$classesIndexMap = array(
    0 => 'valign',
    1 => 'lalign',
    2 => 'talign',
    5 => 'valign',
    6 => 'talign',
    7 => 'lalign',
);
$html_view_more = htmlspecialchars($text_view_more, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>     
<?php foreach($spacategories as $i => $spacategory) : ?>
<li class="<?= isset($spacategory[$i]) ? $spacategory[$i] : 'ralign' ?>">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($spacategory['thumb'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>"
             title="<?= htmlspecialchars($spacategory['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>"
             alt="<?= htmlspecialchars($spacategory['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>" />

    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3><?= htmlspecialchars($spacategory['name'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></h3>
        <p><?= substr($spacategory['description'],0,150); ?></p>
        <a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($spacategory['href'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"
           class="learmmore"><?= $html_view_more ?></a>
    </div>   
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```